# How to use separate parameter packs for in and out parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to have a function that accepts an arbitrary number of in and out parameters:

```cpp
template<typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
void foo(Inputs... inputs, Outputs*... outputs)
{
   // ...
}
```

Example call:

```cpp
uint32 o1 = 0;
double o2 = 0.0;
bool o3 = false;

foo(1, 2, &o1, &o2, &o3);
```

However, this does not compile, as the compiler attempts to match all parameters into the second parameter pack. I hoped that it could use the `*` as indication where to split the two packs.

Any hints how this could be resolved?

Comment: Only the last parameter can be an expanded variadic template parameter pack. You could wrap the inputs into an `std::tuple`.

Comment: "a function that accepts an arbitrary number of in and out parameters" and does *what*  with them?

Comment: @Caleth The function needs to convert the parameters to some variant types. It is intended as a thin wrapper for some C library function.

Comment: so why not `template<typename... Params> void foo(Params... params) { /* other stuff */ c_function(params...); }`?

Answer (score 5):

```
auto foo = []( auto... Inputs ){
  return [=](auto*... Outputs){
    return 7;
  };
};
```

Now, `foo(3,4,5)(&a,&b,&c)` does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell how many of the arguments belong to which variadic pack; hence deduction of variadic packs is allowed only when it's the last argument.

You can instead wrap `inputs` into a `std::tuple` like this

```
template<typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
void foo(const std::tuple<Inputs...>& inputs, Outputs*... outputs)
{
    // ...
}

int main() {
    int o1 = 0;
    double o2 = 0.0;
    bool o3 = false;

    foo(std::tuple(1, 2), &o1, &o2, &o3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use output parameters

```
template<typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
std::tuple<Outputs...> foo_impl(Inputs... inputs)
{
    return { /* ??? */ };
}

template<typename... Inputs>
std::tuple<determine_outputs...> foo(Inputs&&... inputs)
{
    return foo_impl<Inputs..., determine_outputs...>(std::forward<Inputs>(inputs)...);
}

uint32 o1 = 0;
double o2 = 0.0;
bool o3 = false;

std::tie(o1, o2, o3) = foo(1, 2);
```

or even better, with C++17

```
auto [o1, o2, o3] = foo(1, 2);
```

With no context of how `Outputs...` is to be determined, you may have to pass a type list parameter too.

```
template<typename... T>
struct type_list {};

template<typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
std::tuple<Outputs...> foo(type_list<Outputs...>, Inputs... inputs)
{
    return { /* ??? */ };
}

auto [o1, o2, o3] = foo(type_list<uint32, double, bool>{}, 1, 2);
```

Comment: What if output parameters are e.g. `std::vector`s? Using output parameters can save some memory allocations. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Evg you dont save allocations, because the vector will be at worst moved

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. Here is a simple example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ya5G75o96